# How to add a control to a form created within the code from one another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok so, I have form 1, which is the main form, then form 2, which was created in the code under a button, like:

```
Form Login = new Form();
```

And so I also did:

```
TextBox email = new TextBox();
TextBox password = new TextBox();
TextBox worldid = new TextBox();
```

And I was wondering how I could get them to go on the Login form from the button? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to create a form in this way? The Form designer is a really good tool.

Comment: Well it is going to have a login system and it will just be so much easier to get the text and everything

Comment: I disagree. It is a lot easier to build your form with the designer and open it from your code. Look at your InitializeComponent in your main Form. You need to replicate that code (and if you insist with the dynamic creation don't forget to add also two buttons for OK and Cancel)

Answer (score 0):

```
Form Login = new Form();

TextBox email = new TextBox() { Location = new Point(20, 20) };
TextBox password = new TextBox() { Location = new Point(20, 45) };
TextBox worldid = new TextBox() { Location = new Point(20, 60) };

Login.Controls.Add(email);
Login.Controls.Add(password);
Login.Controls.Add(worldid);
```

but, You have to play a lot. Also give labels.  *The Form designer is a really good tool* (@Steve).

Comment: I suppose that also two buttons for OK and Cancel are needed.

Comment: You're absolutely right. But it only sport, understand how works.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to learn about making forms and adding controls programitically is to make it visually in form designer and then look at the Form1.Designer.cs file. Look under "Windows Form Designer generated code" region to see how to add controls and change their properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (Form Login = new Form())
{
    var email = new TextBox() { Name="emailtxt", Location = new Point(20, 20) };
    var password = new TextBox() { Name="passwordtxt", Location = new Point(20, 45) };
    var worldid= new TextBox() { Name="worldidtxt", Location = new Point(20, 60) };
    Login.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{email , password, worldid});
    Login.ShowDialog();
}
```